# having trouble removing data from arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, methods

im having issues searching the array for "sales rep's name" then removing name, sale, and commission.

```
static void RemoveSale(string[] sellerNames, double[] sellerSales, double[] sellerCommision, ref int sellerCount)
    {
        int index;
        string salesRep;
        try
        {
            if (sellerCount > 0)
            {
                salesRep = GetValidName("Enter the sales rep to delete");
                index = SearchSeller(sellerNames, sellerCount);
                if (index == -1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("that sales rep is not on the team");
                }
                else
                {
                    sellerSales[index] = sellerSales[sellerCount - 1];
                    sellerNames[index] = sellerNames[sellerCount - 1];
                    sellerCommision[index] = sellerCommision[sellerCount - 1];
                    Console.WriteLine("Sales rep {0} has been deleted.", sellerNames);
                    sellerCount--;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("there are no sales reps to delete");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }


    static int SearchSeller(string[] sellerNames, int sellerCount)
    {
        try
        {
            int index = 0;
            bool found = false;
                            while (!found && index < sellerCount)
            {
                if (sellerNames[sellerCount] == sellerNames[index])
                    found = true;
                else
                    index++;
            }
            if (!found)
                index = -1;
            return index;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            Console.ReadLine();
        return 0;
        }

    }
```

expected result is remove name, data, and confirm that sellerName{0} has been deleted.

acutal result is nothing is removed, and no confirmation of removed seller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing your `salesRep` object to the search function. Assuming you can change the signature of the search function try this:

```
// Pass the name of the sales rep
static int SearchSeller(string[] sellerNames, int sellerCount, string salesRep)
    {
        try
        {
            int index = 0;
            bool found = false;
                            while (!found && index < sellerCount)
            {
                // compare the current name in array with the passed name
                if (salesRep == sellerNames[index])
                    found = true;
                else
                    index++;
            }
            if (!found)
                index = -1;
            return index;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            Console.ReadLine();
        return 0;
        }
```

Debugging usually should be the first step to check on the easier mistakes.

A better option to search would be to use c# function [Find](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.find?view=netframework-4.7.2)

```
Array.Find(sellerNames, salesRep);
```

Comment: that was exactly it! thank you.  I'm down to the last few error checks before the assignment is due. your a life saver!! The teacher isn't letting us use find, sort, or list unfortunately